Can I use Durarock concrete board as skirting on a mobile home in Connecticut?
I want to use Durarock cement board as skirting on my mobile home in Connecticut. A New England climate. It will be exposed to weather year round. I want to paint it and make it look like a foundation. Will it work? Or do I need to do something besides paint it to hold up to the weather?

Durarock is (the type sold at big box at least) is not supposed to be installed exteriorly touching the ground.
A much much much better option is the James Hardie paneling that is made for skirting.   These have a "harder" shell, look better and paint easier than durarock.

Yes, it will work but remember that the cement board is not waterproof. It will absorb moisture so you'll want to seal it first with a waterproof sealer/primer and then cover with an exterior paint.

Absorbs moisture + freezing winter weather probably means it will spall, not that I've tried it, as it seems inadvisable.

@Ecnerwal  Why you'd have to seal it first.  :-)
